# Error when launching Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

Versions:

OS: VM with Ubuntu 16.04

Node: v8.11.4

PostgreSQL: 9.5.14

docker : 18.06.1-ce

docker-compose: 1.13.0

I am following this hyperledger composer tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html.
After running the command:

```
./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a
```

I have joined a third organization to the business network by typing:

```
eyfn.sh generate -c mychannel
eyfn.sh up -c mychannel -s couchdb
```

Then I have built the composer business network successfully and tested in the playground

I intended to use the Hyperledger Explorer tool to visualize the number of transactions and its details.

I performed step by step following this link: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

My config.json is the following:

```
{
  "network-config": {
    "org1": {
      "name": "Org1",
      "mspid": "Org1MSP",
      "peer1": {
        "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7051",
        "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7053",
        "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "peer2": {
        "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:8051",
        "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:8053",
        "server-hostname": "peer1.org1.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "admin": {
        "key":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
        "cert":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
      }
    },
    "org2": {
      "name": "Org2",
      "mspid": "Org2MSP",
      "peer1": {
        "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:9051",
        "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:9053",
        "server-hostname": "peer0.org2.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "peer2": {
        "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:10051",
        "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:10053",
        "server-hostname": "peer1.org2.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "admin": {
        "key":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore",
        "cert":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts"
      }
    },
    "org3": {
      "name": "Org3",
      "mspid": "Org3MSP",
      "peer1": {
        "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:11051",
        "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:11053",
        "server-hostname": "peer0.org3.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/org3-artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "peer2": {
        "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:12051",
        "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:12053",
        "server-hostname": "peer1.org3.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/org3-artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "admin": {
        "key":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/org3-artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp/keystore",
        "cert":
          "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/org3-artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp/signcerts"
      }
    }
  },
  "channel": "mychannel",
  "orderers": [
    {
      "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
      "server-hostname": "orderer.example.com",
      "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7050",
      "tls_cacerts":
        "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
    }
  ],
  "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
  "configtxgenToolPath": "/home/diogosilva/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/bin",
  "SYNC_START_DATE_FORMAT": "YYYY/MM/DD",
  "syncStartDate": "2018/01/01",
  "eventWaitTime": "30000",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "version": "1.1"
}
```

When typing in a new console the command to start the Hyperledger Explorer:

```
./start.sh
```

The Hyperledger Explorer does not start and in the console logs is thrown the following error:

```
 postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
    at Platform.initialize (/home/diogosilva/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/Platform.js:52:45)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
Closed out connections
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
at Platform.initialize (/home/kp/Desktop/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/Platform.js:52:45)
```

According to Platform.js, it means to have been failed to load your config.json in some reason. You need to review with the following view points:

- Check logs/app/app.log
- Difference from orignal config.json
- Version ( Which version are you using ? Fabric 1.1 or 1.2 / Explorer release 3.5 or 3.6 )